# Float paragraph with undefined width

Tags: css, css-float

I have a div containing four elements labelled 1, 2, 3 and 4, as seen in the diagram below, where #4 is the only element with an undefined height and width. I would like #2 to float right of #1, and #4 to float right of #3, but, #4 just sits below #3 rather than to the right of it. I have created a diagram to illustrate my intention.

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding:20px;
  background-color: #ff6666;
}

#a {
  margin:10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #14165b;
}

#b {
  margin:10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #14165b;
}

#c {
  margin:10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  clear:left;
  background-color: #14165b;
}

#d {
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #9536ff;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="c"></div>
  <p id="d">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

**Diagram**

[image]

Comment: The minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem belongs directly into your question (preferably as a code snippet), not just dumped on an external site.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the advice. I have replaced the fiddle with a code snippet.

Comment: Not sure what you want is possible without specifying at least a max-width for the paragraph.

Comment: I'd suggest perhaps using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below solution I wrapped rows with `<div class="row">` and used `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` for parent `#container`. `.row` is also flex and has `justify-content: space-between` to ensure that distance between it's children is as big as possible. I also changed `#a`, `#b` and `#c` parameter `width` to `min-width`, so flexbox would respect that.

If you are new to flexbox I recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ff6666;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#a {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #14165b;
}

#b {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #14165b;
}

#c {
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  background-color: #14165b;
}

#d {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #9536ff;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="c"></div>
    <p id="d">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to flex boxes. This answer was very useful.